# Poner 2 parametros a un buscador

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Estoy haciendo un buscador sencillo para luego imprementarlo a mi sistema, hasta el momento el buscador solo funciona con el campo **name** pero estoy deseando que funcione tambien con mi campo **ingredient** como puedo hacer para que mi consulta tome en cuenta al campo **ingredient**,ya en estos momentos solo toma en cuenta al campo **name**

```
$con = Conectar();
 $id = $_POST['documento'];
 $SQL = 'SELECT  id, name, ingredient, cantidad FROM cobertura WHERE name=:doc, ingredient=:do ' ;
 $stmt = $con->prepare($SQL);
 $result = $stmt->execute(array(':doc'=>$id, ':do'=>$id));
 $rows = $stmt->fetchALL(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

 if (count($rows)){

    foreach ($rows AS $row){
?>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Informacion del usuario: <?php print($id)?></div>
      
      <!--     <?php print("Nombre y ingrediente: ".$row->name." ".$row->ingredient."<br>")?> -->
      <div class="panel-body">
   
      <?php print("Nombre: ".$row->name."<br>")?>
      <?php print("Ingrediente: ".$row->ingredient."<br>")?>
      <?php print("Cantidad: ".$row->cantidad."<br>")?>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Si necesitas que los 2 parámetros sean necesarios para filtrar entonces quita la coma entre ellos y agrega el operador `AND` y en el otro caso si son opcionales entonces sustituye la coma por el operador `OR`

Comment: Perfecto, me funciono!

Comment: Si gustas para que no quede abierta la pregunta, puedes publicar la solución y marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que filtre correctamente se necesita del operador **`OR`** envés de la coma.

```
$SQL = 'SELECT  id, name, ingredient, cantidad FROM cobertura WHERE name=:doc OR ingredient=:do ' ;
```